# Pass variable to array index

Tags: php, arrays, debugging, multidimensional-array, indexing

Here's what I have

```
foreach ( $post_formats as $format ) {
    if ( $options['show_post_formats'][$format] == 0 ) {
        $format = 'post-format-' . $format;
        array_push( $hide, $format );
    }
}
```

and it works fine ... but gives me an Undefined index: error when I debug because it wants the value of $format to be in quotes. How would I do this properly?

Comment: We need to see more code

Comment: ok but it's the $format is what the debugger has a problem with because it's expecting the value to be in quotes

Comment: As @MathieuImbert stated, more source would be of great use, but you can check if an index exists with [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: @byronyasgur A specific `$format` doesn't exist in your array, you should go with Lawrence's answer.

Comment: think I might have had the wrong idea about what the problem was

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as your not sure the index will be there you simply use !empty() and check the array key exists.

```
<?php 
foreach ( $post_formats as $format ) {
    if (!empty($format) && array_key_exists($format, $options['show_post_formats']) && $options['show_post_formats'][$format] == 0 ) {
        $format = 'post-format-' . $format;
        array_push( $hide, $format );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: not sure I understand ... do I drop the entire foreach into this?

Comment: There was no foreach when I answered, anyways `$format` could possible be an empty value or blank thus causing the problem. Updated